# Using seq to cut every other column from a large file

Tags: bash, cut, seq

I wanted to print only every other column in a file (with over 1 million columns) so first I tried using seq on a subset of data:

```
    cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 filename > filename.test
    cut -d ' ' -f$(seq -s, 1 2 12) filename.test > filename.testout
```

That works--I end up with half as many columns as the first file. However when I try the same approach on the full dataset like so:

```
    cut -d ' ' -f$(seq -s, 1 2 1211418) file > fileout
```

I get this error:

```
    -bash: /bin/cut: Argument list too long
```

So what do I do if I need only every other column from a file with this many columns? Thanks!

I referenced [using cut command to remove multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690461/using-cut-command-to-remove-multiple-columns) but I'm stuck on how to make it work for my huge file...

Answer (score 2):

Use a different tool.

```
perl -F'/\x20/' -ane 'print $F[0]; for ( $i=2 ; $i<=$#F ; $i+=2 ) { print " $F[$i]" } print "\n"'
```

`-F` tells Perl to split on a space (\x20). `-a` tells Perl to split into the `@F` array. `-n` tells Perl to process the input line by line without printing each line. `-e` introduces the expression. `$#F` is the index of the last element in the @F array.

Answer (score 2):

> So what do I do if I need only every other column from a file with
>   this many columns?

Instead of attempting to use a tool that requires you to pass the fields explicitly on the command line that cause the *argument list too long* error, use something that doesn't require you to do that.  Using `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2){printf "%s ", $i}{printf "%s", RS}}' filename
```

Or, using `perl`:

```
perl -lane 'print join" ",@F[map {$_*2} 0..int($#F/2)]' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){if(i<NF-1){printf "%s ", $i} else{printf "%s", $i}}{print "";}}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try this awk solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" " ; OFS=FS}
     { for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {printf("%s%s",$i,OFS)}
       printf("\n","")
     } INPUTFILE
```

Comment: A typo I guess `printf("%s%s",i,OFS)` shouldn't be `printf("%s%s",$i,OFS)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html) to extract every senond column:

```
sed -r 's/ [^ ]*( |$)/\1/g' file > fileout
```

here assuming your delimiter is `space`.