# Import selected columns from csv in h2o

Tags: r, h2o

I have a csv file which is more than 20gb. I can read the first few lines using readlines and then figure out which columns I want to import. Is it possible to import only these columns using `h2o.importFile()` or some other way in h2o so that I am not loading unnecessary columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `h2o.importFile()` function does not support loading only a subset of the columns.  Here are some work-arounds:

- Load in the entire dataset and use the `x` argument in any modeling function to ignore certain columns.  `fit <- h2o.gbm(x = good_cols, y = y, training_frame = train)`
- Load in the entire dataset and then create a new H2OFrame which only contains the columns you want.  `newdf <- df[, good_cols]`
- Create a copy of your data on disk that contains only the columns you want.  This is easy to do using the `cut` tool ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690461/using-cut-command-to-remove-multiple-columns#13690563)).  `cut -d, -f2-4,6-10 train.csv > newtrain.csv`

Comment: +1 for `cut` (I am amazed I never knew about that command!). I guess the point of the question was "20gb is too big to fit in memory", so the other solutions won't be usable.