# Show particular column for command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I want to show only specific columns for all the records in the command.

Example: `docker ps` shows me data in 10 columns. It can have space in between the column headers. My requirement is to get only 2-4 columns in some sequence.

Is there a direct way to do that in any of the commands that respond in a tabular way?

I am new to Linux and thinking if this can be feasible. Thanks.

---

For example:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE   COMMAND     CREATED             NAMES
123           image   "ABC DEF"   10 hours ago        image ABC
```

Here in the above scenario, `CONTAINER ID` is one header column but there is space, and in the row for `NAMES` columns can have space in between.

Using `AWK`, `CUT` etc it is trickier to write a common script for all the commands because they work on "space" logic.

Comment: read `man docker-ps` -- there's a handy `--format` option that does just what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify more spaces for the delimiter using cut?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7142735/608639), [Using cut command to remove multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13690461/608639), etc.

Comment: its not related to docker ps only, but i need some common script for all the commands

Answer (score 10):

You can use `awk` like that:

```
$ ps | awk '{print $2 " " $3 " " $4}'
TTY TIME CMD
pts/22 00:00:00 bash
pts/22 00:00:00 ps
pts/22 00:00:00 awk
```

Or together with `column -t` for more readable output:

```
$ ps | awk '{print $2 " " $3 " " $4}' | column -t
TTY     TIME      CMD
pts/22  00:00:00  bash
pts/22  00:00:00  ps
pts/22  00:00:00  awk
pts/22  00:00:00  column
```

As [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) noted in the comment below `awk` command can be simplified:

```
$ ps | awk '{print $2, $3, $4}' | column -t
TTY    TIME      CMD
pts/9  00:00:00  bash
pts/9  00:00:00  ps
pts/9  00:00:00  awk
pts/9  00:00:00  column
```

Comment: this will work, but it will fail when the column heading or the data have spaces in that.

`command`

SR NO   DETAIL DATE

here awk print 1 will be SR, print 2 will be NO

Comment: This is how `awk` works, it separates columns by a whitespace.  To do
what you want you have to use some `ps` options to tell it to display
only some columns.  Post entire output of `docker ps` and `ps
--version`.

Comment: yes, awk works that way, so is there any other way?

`ps` option in this case is the command to docker, so passing column name will not work.

Comment: Probably cleaner to write `print $2, $3, $4`

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: For this particular `docker ps` example it is possible to use more than one space as a separator in awk:
`docker ps | awk -F ' {2,}'  '{print $2 " " $3 " " $4}'`

Answer (score 8):

Piping the output to **tr** and **cut**:

```
docker ps | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2-4
```

*-s* flag on **tr** squeezes characters and leaves only one " "

*-d* on cut tells to split field by " ".

Comment: Docker actually has a filter
docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}"

Replace ID or Names with whatever columns you want

Answer (score 1):

Sample output using Perl. Perl has 0 based index, so you have to use 1..3 meaning from 2 to 4

```
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
    14556   11424   14556       6944  cons0     197609 22:10:27 /usr/bin/ps
    11424       1   11424      11424  cons0     197609 22:41:21 /usr/bin/bash
$ ps | perl -F'\s+' -lane ' print "@F[1..3]" '
PID PPID PGID
11208 11424 11208
11424 1 11424
380 11424 11208
```

If you don't need headers.. then

```
$ ps | perl -F'\s+' -lane 'if($.>1) { print "@F[1..3]" } '
6072 11424 6072
11424 1 11424
```